# InAppPurchase2 / Capacitor / Ionic: How to sell testperiod products (Offer / Discount)

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, capacitor, ionic-native

I`m using In App Purchase in my Ionic App installed like described in

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/in-app-purchases

With this npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2

This works fine when purchasing products.

Now I want to add a test period for my product. User should be able to test for 7 days. So I created a offer in Play Console:

[image]

How to tell InAppPurchase2 to use the offer? `store.order()` only takes product_id and an additionalData object. How to pass the offer id? Is it possible in additional params?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution: `"cordova-plugin-purchase": "^13.0.0"` is needed. And `"@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-purchase-2"` which is kind of an interface for  `"cordova-plugin-purchase": "^11.0.0"` is outdated.

When using version 13 of `"cordova-plugin-purchase"` with plain javascript (no other library), you get the offers in the product object and can order it with  something like store.order(product.offers[0]).